# How can I make Matlab Compiler run faster?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

How can I make the Matlab Compiler run faster?
It takes ages for it to make a sensible program.

I am currently using 
**Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 in c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0** 
in **mbuild -setup**

Comment: I agree, it takes for ever (with linux too)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one tip - a large part of the time taken by MATLAB Compiler is in dependency checking for the code you're compiling. If you have a large number of toolboxes on the path, this can take a long time. You can change the list of toolboxes on the path from the Settings menu in `deploytool`. Make sure that only the toolboxes your code actually uses are selected.

It may still take ages, but this can make it take slightly less ages.

Comment: Think of it as an opportunity to take a well-earned break - maybe a nice coffee or a short walk. You deserve it.

Comment: Reminds me of when I was using `addpath` a bit like the C `include` statement and putting at the top of functions called multiple times. I discovered this one line was taking up around 80% of execution time...

Answer (score -2):

Usual techniques for making anything compile faster as usually pretty cost-effective:

- Faster CPU
- More memory
- SSD

I don't think that the parallel computing toolbox will help you because the MATLAB compiler isn't listed as having [built-in support](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/parallel-computing/builtin-parallel-support.html) on the website even though the coder products do.